# WLAN works, LAN does not, certain websites in browser unable to connect, ping www.google.com connect: Network is unreachable

Tags: linux, networking, router, ethernet, ping

My operating system is Ubuntu 16.04. I think I did something wrong in the past. I always used WLAN to connect to the internet and everything was fine. Today I wanted to use LAN, but it does not work properly.

First, for many websites in Firefox I get: "Unable to connect". Google works, but many other sites doesn't (for example speedtest.net).

Secondly in my Terminal I can't ping anything. For example `ping www.google.com`. I get `connect: Network is unreachable`

Again, WLAN works fine, but LAN does not.

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:00:02:54  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2420 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2686690 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:207739 (207.7 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2500000-f2520000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1399 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1399 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:129446 (129.4 KB)  TX bytes:129446 (129.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:c7:54:99:0a  
          inet addr:192.168.178.40  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:c7ff:fe54:990a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2370 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1117949 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:433103 (433.1 KB)
```

ip a:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:de:f1:00:02:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:26:c7:54:99:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.40/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 863788sec preferred_lft 863788sec
    inet6 fe80::226:c7ff:fe54:990a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route:

```
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1  metric 100
```

ip -6 route:

```
2a02:908:1473:3b20::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 7111sec pref medium
2a02:908:1473:3b20::/59 via fe80::ca0e:14ff:fe91:4c8b dev eth0  proto ra  metric 100  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
default via fe80::ca0e:14ff:fe91:4c8b dev eth0  proto static  metric 100  pref medium
```

ping6 www.google.com:

```
PING www.google.com(ams17s01-in-x04.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ams17s01-in-x04.1e100.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=35.1 ms
64 bytes from ams17s01-in-x04.1e100.net: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=33.7 ms
64 bytes from ams17s01-in-x04.1e100.net: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=24.9 ms
```

Comment: Reboot the router and try again. Also, of course, check the cable.

Comment: The router and the cable are fine. Because on my Desktop PC the LAN works. But this is my Notebook, where it doesn't work.

Comment: `eth0` looks fine. What's the output of `ip route` and `ip -6 route`? (Please don't include screenshots, instead edit the question, and indent the output by 4 blanks to format it properly). What happens if you do `ping -6 www.google.com`?

Comment: I edited my post and added the output of the things you said.

Comment: It looks like your LAN interface is down for some reason.  Are you using dhcp on your LAN?  Have you attempted to set a static ip on the lan interface to see if that works?  It’s interesting that ipv6 appears to be working

Comment: Also your route output points to 10.x.x.x, but I do not see any indication of your eth0 adapter being attached to 10.x.x.x

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't use DHCP. For some reason I had the method 'Manual' selected with the address 10.0.0.1.

So the solution: Edit Connections... -> Edit Wired connection -> IPv4 Settings -> Method: Automatic (DHCP) and then restart the Computer.

Comment: If you didn't use DHCP, how did `eth0` get the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in the picture you used before the edit? Also, `eth0` had `LOWER_UP` (so the LAN interface at that time wasn't down).

Comment: I didn't use DHCP for IPv4, but for IPv6 I did. Here is the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZLpv.png

Sorry, I don't know much about this stuff.